# Wordpress logout only one specific user after 15 minutes of inactivity

Tags: wordpress, cookies, logout

Hello I have one specific user I need to keep track of. I need to know about what times they logon every day and how many times to be sure they are checking my site. I am using a user login log plugin which kinda works, but it only makes a record after the auth cookie expires and forces them to relogin.

Ideally, I would like to add something to my functions.php that forces him to relogin if hes been idle or away from the site for 15 minutes. I know wordpress creates a cookie to track this but so far I have been unsuccessful in reading it to get an accurate time. Any help is appreciated

Comment: again, found my answer on my own.